# Visual Studio freezes during XamlParseException

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, xamlparseexception

Visual Studio 2013 always freezes when XAML parser throw XAMLParseException. It takes sometimes one minute when VS throw exception. It exist some settings how to avoid this behavior?

Comment: So instead of fixing the exception, you just want to avoid the freeze when it occurs?

Comment: `It exist some settings how to avoid this behavior?` - Disable the VS XAML designer, you don't really need it, invoke it manually only when needed by pressing F7.